# How to generate CRMF request with SubjectAltName?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, x509, pki

I have to generate a CRMF request that will then be processed by a CA that issues a certificate if the request is alright. One of the things the must be verified is the *SubjectAltName* inside the request.

Populating the *SubjectAltName* field is not straightforward. The [generateCRMFRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_crypto/generateCRMFRequest) function in JavaScript doesn't seem to be able to do so, there is no reference to X509 extensions in the documentation.

- Can someone recommend an approach to deal with this in JS?
- Is another way to generate such requests using existing free software?

Comment: why can't you use the `requestedDN` argument to `generateCRMFRequest()`?

Comment: I have to implement a system according to specs I get from elsewhere, the requirements state that the string must be stored in `subjectAltName`, so I have no choice.

Comment: My bad, I misread your question. It does indeed look to be very hard to do this with the Mozilla function. I would myself give up completely on Javscript and try using Java instead.

Comment: The CA must support several request types - `CRMF` and `PKCS#10` are among them. My system is an intermediate component between the CA and another module (outside of my jurisdiction). Technically, it doesn't matter how exactly the request is generated; but there is a great probability that eventually I'll have to create a web-page people can use to request certificates - which is why I prefer JavaScript.